# Workaround for modules' dependency on Terraform 0.11 does not work

Tags: terraform

I am trying to create an implicit module dependency in my `main.tf`, so that `jenkins` module is created after `kube` module.

```
module "jenkins" {
  install_jenkins = "${var.install_jenkins}"
  env_name = "${var.env_name}"
  source        = "../../../../modules-terraform/jenkins_module"
  sync_var = "${module.kube.cluster_name}"
}

module "kube" {
  source        = "../../../../modules-terraform/kube_module"
  cluster_count = "${var.gke_cluster_create}"

}
```

So (as it can be seen from the code above) I have created the (not otherwise needed) `sync_var` for module `jenkins`.

This is declared in `variables.tf` of **module `jenkins`**

```
variable "sync_var" {
  description = "Dummy variable used for synchronization with kube_module"
  default     = ""
}
```

and the `cluster_name` is of course in `output.tf` of **module `kube`**

```
output "cluster_name" {
  value = "${google_container_cluster.k8s.0.name}"
}
```

The `apply` process however (in which `main.tf` encompasses the initial tf snippet at the beginning of this post) seems not to be taking into account the above.

The resources of these two modules are created in parallel.

Using Terraform `0.11.14`.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention in your question any references to `var.sync_var`. Without at least one resource depending on that variable, its dependencies won't have any useful effect because variables themselves have no externally-visible side-effects.

For Terraform 0.12 an explicity dependency on the variable can be achieved by just directly referring to it in `depends_on`, like this:

```
resource "example" "example" {
  # This resource depends on anything that
  # var.sync_var depends on.
  depends_on = [var.sync_var]

  # ...
}
```

---

In Terraform 0.11 `depends_on` only works with resources directly, so we need to introduce an extra resource to bridge the dependency from the variable to other resources' `depends_on`:

```
resource "null_resource" "example" {
  triggers = {
    # By referring to the variable, this resource
    # implicitly depends on anything var.sync_var
    # depends on.
    dependency = "${var.sync_var}"
  }
}


resource "example" "example" {
  # This resource depends on anything that
  # null_resource.example depends on, which
  # includes everything that var.sync_var
  # depends on.
  depends_on = ["null_resource.example"]

  # ...
}
```